in blender 4.1 is it possible to add vertex groups without pre-existing geometry with pre-existing groups?
I have only seen blender 3.0 workarounds. Is this no longer issue in blender 4.1?
if it is no longer issue, how does one create group?
I have tried 'named attribute' but does not work so assuming it still broken/not function.

The latest workaround I am aware of is detailed in this post: Is it possible to generate a vertex group using geometry nodes?.

i  found am using this https://blenderartists.org/t/can-geometry-nodes-output-a-vertex-group-other-next-modifier-could-see-and-use/1484924/6 ill have look at them two solutions

I don't have enough rep to put it on the comments  in other post seems
